# Sum of a Measurable Set and Open Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be a measurable set and $V \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ an open set. I want to show that $E + V$ is measurable.

Since $E$ is measurable, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $U$ containing $E$ such that

$$m^*(U \setminus E) < \epsilon$$

My thought was to consider $V+U$, which is obviously an open set containing $E + V$, and argue that $m((V+U) \setminus (E +V))$ is less than some expression involving just $\epsilon > 0$. But I don't see how to rewrite $(V+U) \setminus (E +V)$ in a way that would suggest how to do that...

Comment: $E+V$ is open as soon as $V$ is, regardless of $E$.

Comment: D'oh and open sets are measurable...Thanks @SaucyO'Path

Comment: Maybe change the second term to closed, or measurable, to make it more interesting